# Direct Sum Question

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ and $W$ be 3-dimensional subspaces of a 4-dimensional vector space $V$, and suppose that $U\neq W$ .  Is $V$ the direct sum of $U$ and $W$?

Answer (score 1):

As you have $\dim U \cap W =2$, $U+W$ can’t be a direct sum.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible.

Note that for a finite number of factors, the direct sum is essentially the same as the product.

(Here, the direct sum $U\oplus W$ is not isomorphic to a subspace of $V$. The normal sum $U+W$ would be equal to $V$, but since $U\cap V \neq 0$  the sum is not a direct sum.)

Comment: You could have given some hint but you chose to give a more wide explanation...yet you didn't explain why $\;U\cap V\neq\{0\}\;$ ...which is fine, but you could as well mention that as a hint.